# VueJs - DOM not updating on array mutation

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a model in which I'm initializing an array on ajax success after the model is mounted

```
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON("somejson.json",
        function (data) {
            var list = [];
            list = data.list.map(function (item) {
                return { id: item.id, text: item.text };
            });

            self.selectableItems = list;
        });
```

I have a click method on each of these items which removes the item from selectableItems

```
        select: function (item) {
            this.selectableItems.pop(item);
        },
```

selectableItems renders correctly initially, but when I mutate the array, the dom isn't updating. Although the actual array is being modified correctly.

I verified this by having a computed property that returns the count of selectableItems. This count is updated correctly when the item is removed, but the dom still shows the item.

I also noticed that when I hard code the value of selectableItems in the ajax, everything works as expected!

```
self.selectableItems = [{ id: 1, text: "adsad"}];
```

I'm aware of the caveats of array mutation in vue. But I feel I'm missing something basic here, as I have just started exploring Vue.
Can someone point out on what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you using `Array.prototype.pop()` for `this.selectableItems.pop(item);`? What is the argument? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: ah pretty stupid of me! i was so into exploring vuejs concepts, i forgot the definition for array.pop(). Thanks anyway!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.pop()` removes the last item from the array, it does not take any argument. It only removes the last item any argument you pass it.

That the reason your computed property showing the array count works as  last item is being removed but not the item you want.

Use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)instead.

pass the index to your click method  like this:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in selectableItems" @click="select(index)>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

**script**

```
select: function (index) {
        this.selectableItems.splice(index, 1);
    },
```